# Spring JPA with H2: Add another Entity with Foreign Key

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have two Entities **Article** and **ArticleDescription**

```
@Entity
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int articleId;

    private String name;
    private String manufactor;
    private float price;

    @ManyToOne
    private ArticleDescription articleDescription;


@Entity
public class ArticleDescription {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int articleDescriptionId;

    private String text;
    private String author;

    // Joshua
    @ManyToOne
    private Article article;
```

I want to have something like this:

```
[
 {
   "articleId": "5",
   "manufactor": "Test",
   "name": "Name",
   "price": "50",
   "ArticleDescription": {
     "articleDescriptionId": "5",
     "test": "Text",
     "author": "Author"
 }
]
```

I do also have an ArticleJpaRepository and an ArticleController:

```
public interface ArticleJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, Integer> {
    List<Article> findByName(String name);

    List<Article> findByManufactor(String manufactor);

    List<Article> findByPrice(float price);
}

@ComponentScan
@RestController
public class ArticleController {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleJpaRepository articleJpaRepository;

    @GetMapping("/articles")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Article> getArticles() {

        return articleJpaRepository.findAll();
    }

    // Optional, falls kein Customer gefunden wird.
    @RequestMapping("/article/{articleId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Optional<Article> getArticle(@PathVariable("articleId") int articleId) {

        return articleJpaRepository.findById(articleId);
    }

    // Client to Server
    // POST über z.B. Postman Client
    @PostMapping("/article")
    public Article addArticle(@RequestBody Article article) {

        articleJpaRepository.save(article);

        return article;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/article/{articleId}")
    public String deleteArticle(@PathVariable int articleId) {

        Article a = articleJpaRepository.getOne(articleId);
        articleJpaRepository.delete(a);

        return "deleted";
    }

    @PutMapping("/customer")
    public Article updateArticle(@RequestBody Article article) {

        articleJpaRepository.save(article);

        return article;
    }
```

I am expecting that when I add an articleDescriptionId to an Article in SQL that they connect. But I dont know where I configure this behaviour. When I want to add the foreign key of article_description to article I get an Error.

```
"Referential integrity constraint violation:
```

SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO article (article_Id, manufactor, name, price, ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION_ARTICLE_DESCRIPTION_ID)
VALUES ('1000', 'koezocakbasi', 'Dürüm', '4.90', '1000'),
       ('1001', 'koezocakbasi', 'Döner', '4.50', '1001'),
       ('1002', 'koezocakbasi', 'DönerTeller', '10.90', '1002');

INSERT INTO article_description (article_Description_Id, author, text)
VALUES ('1000', 'koezocakbasi', 'Dürüm'),
       ('1001', 'koezocakbasi', 'Döner'),
       ('1002', 'koezocakbasi', 'DönerTeller');
```

Comment: First insert the id in article table if article table is not containing any foreign key. Then, insert record for same ids in article description table and do make sure you aint inserting duplicates as well

Comment: that was the problem @HimanshuAhuja . I just swapped both SQL Statements and it worked.

Comment: so i believe your problem is fixed now